# In this case which is better in matching regular expression or parse_url

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Suppose we have the following link

```
$link = "http://www.mysite.com/bbbbbbb.flv?something";
```

And we want to matching it.

Upon this question [how to match links that has extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244642/how-to-match-links-that-has-extension) @Thanks to all@
We have two ways `regular expression` and `parse_url`

So my question which is better in your point of view and for my website (such as fast better accurate ..etc)?

**Method 1** `regular expression`

```
if (preg_match('/\.flv(\?|$)/i', $link)) {
    echo 'It has flv';
} else {
    echo 'It does not have';
}
```

**Method 2** `parse_url`

```
$arr = parse_url($link);

$pathParts = pathinfo($arr['path']);

if ($pathParts['extension'] == 'flv')
   echo "valid extension";
else
   echo "invalid extension";
```

@ Thanks

Comment: You're fishing for opinions. That's not what this site is about. I'd go `substr($link, -4, 4) == '.flv'`

Comment: You sould not trust on file extension, check the headers of the file instead.

Comment: @Babblo thanks for your warning but it would be external links not related to upload/download/streaming activities just links shown in text file but i need to know its extension to provide some informations.

Comment: `parse_url` will only work if the input string is a valid URL whereas the regex will accept even `.FLV`.  The answer depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this publication](http://books.google.ca/books?id=mCpnlNYzqOQC&pg=PT732&lpg=PT732&dq=is%20parse_url%20faster%20than%20preg_match?&source=bl&ots=qzZXezlo-6&sig=KX8areZ0ht01SrN3g_PmDi_IZEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=syeWUvDgE4zWoASw04KoAQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=parse_url&f=false), using the built in `parse_url` is much slower than `preg_match`. This is understandably the case, because the regular expression captures a single result, whereas `parse_url` captures and parses all components of the url.

Comment: thank you so much for this informations, i spent my life thinking that `preg_match` is slowest

Comment: It is actually `speed vs accuracy` paradigm. Writing a full blown regex to parse various components of a URL can be very challenging. `parse_url` is definitely doing to work with a valid URL.

Comment: @anubhava touché. If we're shooting for accuracy, `parse_url` wins every time. (And why would you reinvent the wheel!?)